# Lograge log my passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm using lograge and I don't know why lograge log passwords in plain text. When I use Rails logging, fields named password are filtered out and replaced by :password=>\"[FILTERED]\"

In application.rb I have folloving config:

```
#rails logging
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :verification]
#lograge loging
config.lograge.enabled        = true
config.lograge.custom_options = lambda { |event| { params: event.payload[:params] } }
```

Here I put sample log wrote by lograge where we can see password:

```
method=POST path=/user_sessions format=html controller= action= status=302 duration=994.36 db=561.11 location=http://site.dev/?logged=1 params={"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HOH2d6Eg3ykBpMsPF0EDKNhgqeR/OtCGPpLAGhKGsJQ=", "user_session"=>{"login"=>"loggg", "password"=>"pass", "remember_me"=>"0"}}
```

Thanks for all answers.

Edit:

Ok I solved this problem. To my application_controller I added:

```
def append_info_to_payload(payload)
  super
  payload[:params] = request.filtered_parameters
end
```